# How to use the fast99 in the sensitivity package

Tags: r

i'm trying to use R for global sensitivity analysis of a function. I'm completely new to R so I'm having a hard time understanding the documentation correctly.
I want to use the fast99 method from the sensitivity package but it returns NaN for 2 of my 4 factors.

I'm using R Studio and the sensitivity package.

My function is

```r
Func<-function(
  Input
){
  alpha<-Input[,1]
  beta<-Input[,2]
  gamma<-Input[,3]
  nu<-Input[,4]
  root<-4*beta+alpha^2*gamma +2*alpha*beta*gamma*nu+beta^2*gamma*nu^2
  denominator<-2*beta*gamma
  summand<-alpha*gamma-beta*gamma*nu
  result<-(summand+sqrt(gamma)*sqrt(root))/denominator
  return(result)
}
```

And then I call

```
library(sensitivity)
factors<-c("alpha","beta", "gamma", "nu")
x<-fast99(Mtb, factors=factors, n=1000, q.arg=list(min=0, max=1))
print(x)
```

I expect the result to be some number for each factor but it returns

```
Call:
fast99(model = Mtb, factors = factors, n = 1000, q.arg = list(min = 0,     max = 1))

Model runs: 4000 

Estimations of the indices:
      first order total order
alpha         NaN         NaN
beta   0.23928895   0.8855446
gamma  0.03075694   0.5991250
nu            NaN         NaN
```

Which can't be since alpha should be important

I found the Problem if I set the minimum Value to 0.001 it works fine, there seems to be a problem with dividing by zero, which irritates me because in the denominator is only beta and gamma. But now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was having 0 as a Minimum Value